# Embedded C counter between two values

Tags: c++, embedded, counter, microcontroller, 8051

Please help with my issue.

I am trying to avoid going out of the limit between 0 to 100 for the count up/down value in the program below;

I am using an 8051 microcontroller and 2x16 LCD to display a value between 0 and 100. when pressing the UP button the number increased by one, while when pressing down button it decreased by one.

my code keeps incrementing the value above 100 and less 0.

```
// This is a code in Embedded C written on MikroC compiler for 8051 microcontroller
// The microcontroller shall count up / down on the LCD when press up / down button. 

unsigned int cntr=0; //  counter value 
char lcdv[6];       // Value to displau on lcd

sbit UP at P3.B7;   // declare button UP at port 3 Bit 7.
sbit DN at P3.B6;   // declare button UP at port 3 Bit 6.

// LCD module connections

sbit LCD_RS at P2_0_bit;      // Declare LCD reset pin.
sbit LCD_EN at P2_1_bit;      // Declare LCD Enable pin.
sbit LCD_D4 at P2_2_bit;      // Declare LCD D4 pin.
sbit LCD_D5 at P2_3_bit;      // Declare LCD D5 pin.
sbit LCD_D6 at P2_4_bit;      // Declare LCD D6 pin.
sbit LCD_D7 at P2_5_bit;      // Declare LCD D7 pin.

// End LCD module connections

char text[16]; // this is stored in RAM



 void main() {                      // Main program


  P3 = 255;         // Configure PORT3 as input

  Lcd_Init();       // Initialize LCD

cntr=0;   // Starting counter value


  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR); 
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);

  while(1) {

   while ((cntrset<=100)&&(cntrset>=0))  // Not sure how to limit Min and Max value.

 {
   wordTostr(cntrset,volset);

   LCD_Out(2,1,volset);

  if (UP==0)
  cntrset ++;
  while (UP==0);

  if (DN==0)
  cntrset=--;
  while (DN==0);
                     }


                }    
                }
```

Comment: Have you thought about trying to not increment if the counter is >= 100 and not decrement if the counter is 0?

Comment: In this question the use of 8051 an LCD, and even the fact that it is embedded is largely irellevant. The question and answer do not rely on either of those. You could reduce the text, tags and code in this question to broaden the audience.  Also the comment says the code is C, but you have tagged it C++.  Which is it?  It is not possible to determine from the code, since it is not strictly valid in either language.  I'd be surprised however that you would use C++ on an 8051.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (UP==0 && cntrset < 100 ) cntrset++; 
while (UP==0); 

if (DN==0 cntrset > 0 ) cntrset--; 
while (DN==0);
```

You may still have an issue with switch bounce causing a single press to result in the counter changing by more than one count.  But that is a different question.

**Regarding comment:** If the increment is not *by-one* and the current value need not be a multiple of the increment, then it is easier to apply saturation instead:

```
if( UP == 0 ) cntrset += increment; 
while (UP==0); 

if( DN == 0 ) cntrset -= increment ; 
while (DN==0); 

if( cntrset < 0 ) cntrset = 0 ;
else if( cntrset > MAX_CNTRSET ) cntrset = MAX_CNTRSET ;
```

For that to work however you must change `cntrset` to `signed int`.  If you'd rather not do that then (assuming 16 bit `unsigned`):

```
...

if( (cntrset & 0x8000u) != 0 ) cntrset = 0u ;
else if( cntrset > MAX_CNTRSET ) cntrset = MAX_CNTRSET ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly.
I have added two buttons to increase/decrease the cntrset by 10.

if I start with one step increment, for example, 5, then increment by 10. the last value will be 105. also becomes negative for decreasing  

 if ((UP==0) && (cntrset < 100)) cntrset++;
  while (UP==0);
  if ((HL==0) && (cntrset < 100)) cntrset=cntrset+10;
  while (HL==0);
if ((DN==0) && (cntrset > 0 )) cntrset--;
while (DN==0);
if ((LL==0) && (cntrset > 0)) cntrset=cntrset-10;
while (LL==0);

Comment: You either need to ask a new question or add information to the existing question if you want help with that.  Code in comments does not really work, and SO is not a discussion forum.

Comment: rather then extra buttons for fast/slow adjust, you might simply increment continuously with a delay while the button is held and use "acceleration", whereby if a button is held down for longer then some threshold, the increment increases.  That way single taps increment by one and holding the button down increments by some larger value - generally more user friendly, and less costly in hardware.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response to my question. It is greatly appreciated.